Asymptotics for minimum of a sequence of random variables
This is a question that I'm sure has been investigated before, but I have found no good search terms for.
Let $X_i$ be a sequence of random variables, independent and uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$. Let $Y_n=\min(X_1,\dots,X_n)$.

Is there an asymptotic which $Y_n$ almost surely follows? More precisely, is there some function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R_+$ such that, almost surely, $Y_n\sim f(n)$?

If we ignore the fact that $Y_i$ are not independent, a Borel-Cantelli argument suggests $f(n)=\frac{\log n}{n}$: for any $c$, $\mathbb P(Y_n>c)=(1-c)^n\sim e^{-cn}$ for small $c$. Letting $c=d\frac{\log n}{n}$, this is asymptotic to $n^{-d}$, which has finite sum for $d>1$ and infinite for $d<1$, so we get $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{Y_n}{(\log n)/n}\leq 1$ almost surely, with equality if we pretend we have independence.

Is the $\limsup$ of $\frac{Y_n}{(\log n)/n}$ actually equal to $1$ almost surely? Is the limit equal to $1$ almost surely? If not, what is the "lower" asymptotic for $Y_n$? For instance, do we at least have $Y_n=\Theta(\frac{\log n}{n})$ almost surely?

Note: I am aware that $nY_n$ converges to an exponential distribution, but I don't think that really helps answer the question, as we are interested in the entire sequence of $Y_n$ rather than their individual terms.

The expected value is $\frac{1}{n+1}$, so it can't be that $Y_n = \frac{\log n}{n}$ almost surely (even with probability at least $\frac{1.01}{\log n}$).

I believe we can show that almost surely $\limsup \frac{nY_n}{\log \log (n)} \le 10$, by defining $Z_k = \max(X_{2^{k-1}+1}, \ldots,x_{2^{k}})$ (they are now independent), bounding $Y_n$ for $2^{k}+1\le n \le 2^{k+1}$ from above by $Z_k$ and repeating your argument.

@AlekseiKulikov I think by "max" you mean "min" (and by "$x_{2^k}$" you mean "$X_{2^k}$").

@AlekseiKulikov Your argument gives an upper bound of $4$. But you don't need independence for this Borel-Cantelli argument, so you actually get $2$ as an upper bound (this is Will Sawin's answer).


do we at least have $Y_n=\Theta(\frac{\log n}{n})$ almost surely?

The answer to this is no. It is not even true that $Y_n=\Theta(\frac{h(n)}{n})$ almost surely (a.s.) for any (deterministic or random) function $h$ such that $h(n)\to\infty$ a.s. (as $n\to\infty$).
Indeed, suppose the contrary: that $\liminf_n nY_n=\infty$ a.s. Then, by the Fatou lemma,
$$
\infty=E\infty\le\liminf_n EnY_n 
=\liminf_n n\frac1{n+1}=1,
$$
a contradiction. $\quad\Box$

Let us now show that $Y_n\not\sim f(n)$ a.s. for any deterministic positive function $f$.
To prove this, suppose the contrary: that $Y_n\sim f(n)$ a.s. for some deterministic positive function $f$. Take any positive sequence $(a_n)$ such that $\sum_n a_n=\infty$. Then
$$\sum_n P(X_n<a_n/2)=\sum_n a_n/2=\infty.$$
So, by the Borel--Cantelli lemma, events $\{X_n<a_n/2\}$ a.s. occur infinitely often (i.o.), that is, for infinitely many values of $n$. Therefore and because $\{X_n<a_n/2\}\subseteq\{Y_n<a_n/2\}$, we see that events $\{Y_n<a_n/2\}$ a.s. occur i.o. Recalling now the assumption that $Y_n\sim f(n)$ a.s., we conclude that $f(n)\le a_n$ i.o. In particular, $f(n)\le \frac1{n\ln n}=o(1/n)$ i.o.
So,
$$Z_n:=nY_n\sim nf(n)=o(1) \tag{1}\label{1}$$
a.s. for $n=n_k$ and $k\to\infty$, where $(n_k)$ is a strictly increasing deterministic sequence of positive integers. Also, $EZ_n^2<2$. So, for $n$ as above,
$$\begin{aligned}
1\leftarrow EZ_n&=EZ_n\,1(Z_n<4)+EZ_n\,1(Z_n\ge4) \\ 
&\le EZ_n\,1(Z_n<4)+EZ_n^2/4 \\ 
&<EZ_n\,1(Z_n<4)+1/2\to1/2  
\end{aligned}$$
by \eqref{1} and dominated convergence. So, we have a contradiction. $\quad\Box$

In fact, $Y_n\not\sim f(n)$ even in probability for any positive deterministic  function $f$.
Indeed, suppose that $Y_n\sim f(n)$ in probability for some positive deterministic function $f$. Then, by the Fatou lemma,
$$1=E\lim_n\frac{Y_n}{f(n)}\le \liminf_n\frac{EY_n}{f(n)}
=\liminf_n\frac{1}{(n+1)f(n)},$$
so that $f(n)\lesssim1/n$. So, $nf(n)\to c$ for some real $c\ge0$, $n=n_k$, and $k\to\infty$, where $(n_k)$ is some strictly increasing sequence of positive integers. So, for such $n$ and $Z_n$ as above,
$$Z_n\to c$$
in probability. Also, $EZ_n\to1$, $EZ_n^2\to2$, and $EZ_n^4\to24$. Take now any real $A>0$. Then
$$E(Z_n-c)^2=E(Z_n^2-2cZ_n+c^2)\to C:=2-2c+c^2,$$
whereas, for $n$ as above,
$$\begin{aligned}
E(Z_n-c)^2
&=E(Z_n-c)^2\,1((Z_n-c)^2\le A)+E(Z_n-c)^2\,1((Z_n-c)^2>A) \\ 
&\le E(Z_n-c)^2\,1((Z_n-c)^2\le A)+E(Z_n-c)^4/A \\ 
&\le E(Z_n-c)^2\,1((Z_n-c)^2\le A)+(EZ_n^4+c^4)/A \\ 
&\to 0+(24+c^4)/A
\end{aligned}$$
by dominated convergence. We conclude that $0<C\le(24+c^4)/A$ for all real $A>0$, a contradiction. $\quad\Box$

Why the downvote???

Thank you, I should have noticed the first part but thanks for spelling it out. Do you have any idea what the expected lower bound should be? A function $g(n)$ such that $\liminf Y_n/g(n)=1$ almost surely?

@Wojowu : I don't know this at this point. Two of your questions posted here have now been answered (and more), even though, according to these guidelines, users should avoid trying to answer posts that "request answers to multiple questions". So, perhaps you can consider posting your remaining questions separately.

You are right, I probably should have put more focus in my question. As you have answered my primary question, I will accept your answer, but I appreciate all the other responses, from you and others, too!

For $g(n)$ a decreasing function, we have $\limsup Y_n/g(n)\geq 1$ if and only if $Y_n> g(n)(1-\epsilon)$ infinitely often. Based on an approach suggested by Aleksei Kulikov, if $n \in [2^k, 2^{k+1}]$ then this implies $X_m > g(n) (1-\epsilon) \geq g(2^{k+1} ) (1-\epsilon)$ for all $m \leq 2^k $ for infinitely many $k$. This is an event with probability $\approx e^{ - 2^k g(2^{k+1} ) (1-\epsilon)}$ and it can only occur with positive probability for infinitely many $k$ if the sum of these probabilities $\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{ - 2^k g(2^{k+1} ) (1-\epsilon)}$ is positive (this direction of Borel-Cantelli not requiring independence).
So $\limsup Y_n/g(n)\geq 1$ with probability $0$ for $g(n) = C \log \log n/n$ as soon as $C>2$.

Let $A_n$ be the event that $Y_{2^n} \geq C (\log n)/2^n$. Then $\mathbb P(A_n) \approx n^{-C}$. For $n<m$, the intersection $A_n \cap A_m$ occurs when $X_k \geq C ( \log n)/2^n$ for $k\leq 2^n$ and $X_k \geq C (\log m)/2^m$ for $2^m < k \leq 2^n$ which has probability $$\approx e^{ - C (  \log n  + \frac{2^m-2^n}{2^m} \log m )} = e^{ C 2^{n-m} \log m} e^{ - C \log n} e^{-C \log m}. $$
This is $(1+o(1) ) n^{-C} m^{-C}$ as long as $m-n > \log N$, since $e^{ C 2^{ -\log_2 N } \log m } \leq e^{ C 2^{-\log N} \log N} = 1+o(1)$. When $m$ is close to $n$, this probability is still bounded by $e^{- C\log n}$. This gives
$$\sum_{m,n \leq N} \mathbb P(A_n \cap A_m) \leq (1+o(1))\sum_{n,m\leq N}  n^{-C} m^{-C} + \sum_{\substack{ n,m \leq  N \\ |n-m| \leq \log \log N}}e^{ - C \log n} \approx (1+o(1)) ((1-C) N^{1-C})^2 + 2 (1-C) N^{1-C}  \log N = (1+o(1)) ((1-C) N^{1-C})^2  $$ as long as $C<1$.
Now $\sum_{n=1}^N \mathbb P(A_n) \approx  N^{1-C} / (1-C)$.
So the ratio$$  \frac{ (\sum_{n=1}^N \mathbb P(A_n) )^2}{ \sum_{m,n \leq N} \mathbb P(A_n \cap A_m) }$$ converges to $1$. By Kochen-Stone, this implies that $A_n$ occurs infinitely often with probability $1$.
In other words, $\limsup Y_n / (\log \log n/n) \geq 1$ with probability $1$.

So $\limsup Y_n / (\log \log n/n) \in [1,2]$ with probability $1$. We cannot change the limsup by changing finitely many values of $X_n$ to something nonzero and so by Kolmogorov's zero-one law, there is a fixed deterministic value in $[1,2]$ that the limsup approaches. I am not sure if this is possible to compute.

@IosifPinelis I deleted what I wrote. Maybe the only thing worth preserving is the statement - or rather, thinking a bit, I think the nicest way to state the result from your argument is the following: It shows that for each positive nonincreasing deterministic sequence $g_n$ we either have $\lim\inf_n \frac{Y_n}{g_n}=0$ almost surely or $\liminf_n \frac{Y_n}{g_n}=\infty$ almost surely.

"I am not sure if this is possible to compute". I think it's $1$ just by changing $2$ to $\lambda$. I made this an answer just to summarize the conclusions obtained to the problem. I hope I didn't make a mistake.

By Iosif Pinelis's answer, there is no function we can really call the $\liminf$.
I think Will Sawin / Aleksei Kulikov showed $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{Y_n}{\log\log n / n} = 1$ almost surely without realizing it.
Will Sawin's answer shows the lower bound. Here's how they showed the upper bound.
Take any $\lambda > 1$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, and note $$\mathbb{P}\bigl[Y_{\lambda^k} > (1+\varepsilon)\frac{\log k}{\lambda^k}\bigr] = \Bigl(1-(1+\varepsilon)\frac{\log k}{\lambda^k}\Bigr)^{\lambda^k} \approx k^{-1-\varepsilon},$$ which is summable in $k$. So, by Borel-Cantelli, $Y_{\lambda^k} \le (1+\varepsilon)\frac{\log k}{\lambda^k}$ for all large $k$. Now, for any large $n$, if $\lambda^k \le n < \lambda^{k+1}$, then $$Y_n \le Y_{\lambda^k} \le (1+\varepsilon)\frac{\log k}{\lambda^k} \le \lambda(1+\varepsilon)\frac{\log \log n}{n}.$$ By choosing $\lambda$ sufficiently close to $1$ and $\varepsilon$ to $0$, we're done.

Looks good to me. Nice observation!

(This is to address the previous comment by the OP. Since the previous answer is already long, this is being done in a separate answer.)
The answer to the mentioned comment is the following: there is no positive nonincreasing deterministic sequence $(g_n)$ such that $g_n\to0$ (as $n\to\infty$) and $\liminf_n \frac{Y_n}{g_n}=1$ a.s.
More specifically, let $H$ denote the set of all positive nonincreasing deterministic sequences $h=(h_n)$ such that $h_n\to0$.
Let us say that $h\in H$ is a lower bound for the $Y_n$'s if a.s. the events $\{Y_n<h_n\}$ occur only finitely often (f.o.), that is, only for finitely many values of $n$. Similarly, let us say that $h\in H$ is a lower bound for the $X_n$'s if a.s. the events $\{X_n<h_n\}$ occur only f.o.
The key observation is that $h\in H$ is a lower bound for the $Y_n$'s if and only if $h$ is a lower bound for the $X_n$'s. See the details on this at the end of this answer.
On the other hand, by the Borel--Cantelli lemma, $h\in H$ is a lower bound for the $X_n$'s if and only if
$$\sum_n P(X_n<h_n)=\sum_n \min(1,h_n)<\infty.$$
Thus, $h\in H$ is a lower bound for the $Y_n$'s if and only if
$$\sum_n h_n<\infty.$$
So, if $h\in H$ is a lower bound for the $Y_n$'s, then $ah$ is a lower bound for the $Y_n$'s for any real $a>0$. Moreover, if $h\in H$ is a lower bound for the $Y_n$'s, then $h/b\in H$ is a lower bound for the $Y_n$'s for some sequence $b\in H$ (so that $b_n\to0$).
We conclude that, indeed, there is no positive nonincreasing deterministic sequence $(g_n)$ such that $g_n\to0$ and $\liminf_n \frac{Y_n}{g_n}=1$ a.s.
Furthermore, for any positive real (deterministic) $A$ and $B$,
there is no positive nonincreasing deterministic sequence $g=(g_n)$ such that $g_n\to0$ and $\liminf_n \frac{Y_n}{g_n}\in[A,B]$ a.s. Indeed, the latter condition would imply that $\frac A2\,g$ is a lower bound for the $Y_n$'s, while $2B\,g$ is not a lower bound for the $Y_n$'s -- which contradicts what was noted above: if $h\in H$ is a lower bound for the $Y_n$'s, then $ah$ is a lower bound for the $Y_n$'s for any real $a>0$.
Details: Note that $Y_n\le X_n$ for all $n$. So, a.s.
$$(\text{the events $\{Y_n<h_n\}$ occur only f.o.})
\implies(\text{the events $\{X_n<h_n\}$ occur only f.o.}).$$
Vice versa, suppose that a.s. the events $\{X_n<h_n\}$ occur only f.o. -- that is, for some random positive integer $N$ and all $n>N$ we a.s. have $X_n\ge h_n$. For each $n$ there is some random $K_n\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $Y_n=X_{K_n}$. Moreover, $Y_n\to0$ a.s. and $X_k>0$ for all $k$ a.s. So, $K_n\to\infty$ a.s. So, there is some random positive integer $N_1\ge N$ such that $k_n>N$ a.s. for all $n>N_1$. So, for all $n>N_1$, a.s.
$$Y_n=X_{K_n}\ge h_{K_n}\ge h_n,$$
so that a.s. the events $\{X_n<h_n\}$ occur only f.o. Thus,
$$(\text{the events $\{X_n<h_n\}$ occur only f.o.})
\implies(\text{the events $\{Y_n<h_n\}$ occur only f.o.})$$
and hence
$$(\text{the events $\{Y_n<h_n\}$ occur only f.o.})
\iff(\text{the events $\{X_n<h_n\}$ occur only f.o.}). \quad\Box$$
